# Problem Implement Update UI with LiveData, Retrofit, Coroutine on Recyclerview : adapter Recyclerview not update

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, kotlin-coroutines, mutablelivedata

I'm newbie use Kotlin on my dev apps android,
and now, I on step learn to implement Update UI with LiveData, Retrofit, Coroutine on Recyclerview. The My Apps:

```
MainActivity > MainFragment with 3 Tab fragment > HomeFragment, DashboardFragment, and SettingsFragment
```

I call function to get data from server on **onCreateView** HomeFragment, and observe this with show shimmer data on my Recylerview when is loading, try update RecyclerView when success, and show view Failed Load -button refresh when error.

The problem is:

- Adapter Recyclerview not Update when success get Data from Server. Adapter still show shimmer data
- With case error (no Internet), i show view Failed Load, with button refresh. Tap to refresh, i re-call function to get data server, but fuction not work correct. Recyclerview show last data, not show Failed Load again.

Bellow my code

**HomeFragment**

```
private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!
private lateinit var adapterNews: NewsAdapter
private var shimmerNews: Boolean = false
private var itemsDataNews = ArrayList<NewsModel>()

override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
_binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
......

newsViewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(NewsViewModel::class.java)
//news
binding.frameNews.rvNews.setHasFixedSize(true)
binding.frameNews.rvNews.layoutManager = llmh
adapterNews = NewsAdapter(itemsDataNews, shimmerNews)
binding.frameNews.rvNews.adapter = adapterNews
// Observe

//get News
newsViewModel.refresh()

newsViewModel.newsList.observe(
            viewLifecycleOwner,
            androidx.lifecycle.Observer { newsList ->
                newsList?.let {
                    binding.frameNews.rvNews.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    binding.frameNews.rvNews.isNestedScrollingEnabled = true
                    binding.frameNews.itemNewsLayoutFailed.visibility = View.GONE
                    if (it.size == 0)
                        binding.frameNews.root.visibility = View.GONE
                    else
                        getDataNews(it)
                }
            })
        newsViewModel.loading.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { isLoading ->
            isLoading?.let {
                binding.frameNews.rvNews.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.frameNews.rvNews.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
                binding.frameNews.itemNewsLayoutFailed.visibility = View.GONE
                getDataNewsShimmer()
            }
        }

        newsViewModel.loadError.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { isError ->
            isError?.let {
                binding.frameNews.rvNews.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                binding.frameNews.itemNewsLayoutFailed.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.frameNews.btnNewsFailed.setOnClickListener {
                    newsViewModel.refresh()
                }

            }
        }
....

return binding.root
}

@SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    private fun getDataNewsShimmer() {
        shimmerNews = true
        itemsDataNews.clear()
        itemsDataNews.addAll(NewsData.itemsShimmer)
        adapterNews.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    private fun getDataNews(list: List<NewsModel>) {
        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), list.size.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        shimmerNews = false
        itemsDataNews.clear()
        itemsDataNews.addAll(list)
        adapterNews.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding=null
    }
```

**NewsViewModel**

```
class NewsViewModel: ViewModel() {

    val newsService = KopraMobileService().getNewsApi()
    var job: Job? = null
    val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, throwable ->
        onError("Exception handled: ${throwable.localizedMessage}")
    }

    val newsList = MutableLiveData<List<NewsModel>>()
    val loadError = MutableLiveData<String?>()
    val loading = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()

    fun refresh() {
        fetchNews()
    }

    private fun fetchNews() {
        loading.postValue(true)
        job = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + exceptionHandler).launch {
            val response = newsService.getNewsList()
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    newsList.postValue(response.body()?.data)
                    loadError.postValue(null)
                    loading.postValue(false)
                } else {
                    onError("Error : ${response.message()} ")
                }
            }
        }
        loadError.postValue("")
        loading.postValue( false)
    }

    private fun onError(message: String) {
        loadError.postValue(message)
        loading.postValue( false)
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        job?.cancel()
    }

}
```

**NewsAdapter**

```
NewsAdapter(
var itemsCells: List<NewsModel?>  = emptyList(),
    var shimmer: Boolean ,
) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>() {

    private lateinit var context: Context

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NewsHomeViewHolder {
        context = parent.context
        return NewsHomeViewHolder(
                NewsItemHomeBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
            )
        

    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NewsHomeViewHolder, position: Int) {
     
            holder.bind(itemsCells[position]!!)
        
    }

    inner class NewsHomeViewHolder(private val binding: NewsItemHomeBinding) :
        ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(newsItem: NewsModel) {
          
            binding.newsItemFlat.newsTitle.text = newsItem.name
            binding.newsItemFlatShimmer.newsTitle.text = newsItem.name

            binding.newsItemFlat.newsSummary.text = newsItem.name
            binding.newsItemFlatShimmer.newsSummary.text = newsItem.name

            if (shimmer) {
                binding.layoutNewsItemFlat.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                binding.layoutNewsItemFlatShimmer.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.layoutNewsItemFlatShimmer.startShimmer()
            } else {

                binding.layoutNewsItemFlat.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.layoutNewsItemFlatShimmer.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return itemsCells.size
    }
```

I hope someone can help me to solve the problem. thanks, sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 different `LiveData`s, right? One with a list of news data, one with a loading error message, and one with a loading state.

You set up an `Observer` for each of these, and that observer function *gets called whenever the `LiveData`'s value updates*. That's important, because here's what happens when your request succeeds, and you get some new data:

```
if (response.isSuccessful) {
    newsList.postValue(response.body()?.data)
    loadError.postValue(null)
    loading.postValue(false)
}
```

which means `newsList` updates, **then** `loadError` updates, **then** `loading` updates.

So your observer functions for each of those `LiveData`s run, in that order. But **you're not testing the new values** (except for null checks), so the code in each one **always runs** when the value updates. So when your response is successful, this happens:

- `newsList` observer runs, **displays as successful**, calls `getDataNews`
- `loadError` observer runs, value is *null* so nothing happens
- `loading` observer runs, value is *false* but isn't checked, **displays as loading**, calls `getDataNewsShimmer`

So even when the response is successful, the last thing you do is display the *loading* state

---

You need to check the state (like `loading`) before you try to display it. But if you check that `loading` is *true*, you'll have a bug in `fetchNews` - that sets `loading = true`, starts a coroutine that finishes *later*, and then immediately sets `loading = false`.

I'd recommend trying to create a class that represents different *states*, with a single `LiveData` that represents the current state. Something like this:

```
// a class representing the different states, and any data they need
sealed class State {
    object Loading : State()
    data class Success(val newsList: List<NewsModel>?) : State()
    data class Error(val message: String) : State()
}

// this is just a way to keep the mutable LiveData private, so it can't be updated
private val _state = MutableLiveData<State>()
val state: LiveData<State> get() = _state

private fun fetchNews() {
    // initial state is Loading, until we get a response
    _state.value = State.Loading
    job = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + exceptionHandler).launch {
        val response = newsService.getNewsList()

        // if you're using postValue I don't think you need to switch to Dispatchers.Main?
        _state.postValue(
            // when you get a response, the state is now either Success or Error
            if (response.isSuccessful) State.Success(response.body()?.data)
            else State.Error("Error : ${response.message()} ")
        )
    }
}
```

And then you just need to observe that `state`:

```
// you don't need to create an Observer object, you can use a lambda!
newsViewModel.state.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { state ->
    // Handle the different possible states, and display the current one

    // this lets us avoid repeating 'binding.frameNews' before everything
    with(binding.frameNews) {
        // You could use a when block, and describe each state explicitly,
        // like your current setup:
        when(state) {
            // just checking equality because Loading is a -singleton object instance-
            State.Loading -> {
                rvNews.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                rvNews.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
                itemNewsLayoutFailed.visibility = View.GONE
                getDataNewsShimmer()
            }
            // Error and Success are both -classes- so we need to check their type with 'is'
            is State.Error -> {
                rvNews.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                itemNewsLayoutFailed.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                btnNewsFailed.setOnClickListener {
                    newsViewModel.refresh()
                }
            }
            is State.Success -> {
                rvNews.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                rvNews.isNestedScrollingEnabled = true
                itemNewsLayoutFailed.visibility = View.GONE

                // Because we know state is a Success, we can access newsList on it
                // newsList can be null - I don't know how you want to handle that,
                // I'm just treating it as defaulting to size == 0
                // (make sure you make this visible when necessary too)
                if (state.newsList?.size ?: 0 == 0) root.visibility = View.GONE
                else getDataNews(state.newsList)
            }
        }

        // or, if you like, you could do this kind of thing instead:
        itemNewsLayoutFailed.visibility = if (state is Error) VISIBLE else GONE
    }
}
```

You also might want to break that display code out into separate functions (like `showError()`, `showList(state.newsList)` etc) and call those from the branches of the `when`, if that makes it more readable

I hope that makes sense! When you have a single value representing a state, it's a lot easier to work with - set the current state as things change, and make your observer handle each possible UI state by updating the display. When it's Loading, make it look like *this*. When there's an Error, make it look like *this*

That should help avoid bugs where you update multiple times for multiple things, trying to coordinate everything. I'm not sure why you're seeing that problem when you reload after an error, but doing this might help fix it (or make it easier to see what's causing it)

Comment: OMG, thanks a lot for your advice, the problem is solved